# SAPUI5 mixing mobile (sap.m) and desktop (sap.ui.commons)

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a desktop SAPUI5 application and need to use TileContainer/Tiles in one of the page but noticed that press event is not working for this. Tried other mobile controls e.g. sap.m.Button press events but they are also not working.
Any idea?

Comment: sap.m controls and their events should work fine in the context you're describing. I've just tried adding an sap.m.Button to a desktop UI5 app and it responds fine to the press event. Can you please give more information as - perhaps the code that you have?

Comment: Regardless of the solution, mixing `sap.m` and `sap.ui.commons` is not a good idea as they are incompatible to each other. Please, take a look at this topic to find out more unsupported combinations: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not adding sap.m in sap-ui-bootstrap, adding this made moible ui controls working.

data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.m"

thanks any way qmacro and Nikolay...

Answer (score 2):

Mobile controls will be work fine with touch events only. You need to set `onclick` events. You have 3 options to do this:

1) Attach `onclick` to target control:

```
var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
    text : "Hello",
    press : function() { alert('You've pressed me!') }
}).attachBrowserEvent('click', 
    function(event){
        sap.ui.getCore().byId(event.target.id).firePress()
    });
```

2) Extend standart mobile controls:

```
sap.m.Button.extend('my.Button');
my.Button.prototype.onclick = function(){
    this.ontap.apply(this, arguments);
};
my.Button.prototype.onmousedown = function(){
    this.ontouchstart.apply(this, arguments);
};
my.Button.prototype.onmousemove = function(){
    this.ontouchmove.apply(this, arguments);
};
my.Button.prototype.onmouseup = function(){
    this.ontouchend.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

3) Modify standart controls(not really good idea):

```
sap.m.Button.prototype.onclick = function(){
    this.ontap.apply(this, arguments);
};
...
```